# python convert a long numeric txt file like for example the first 16 milion Pi numbers and save it to a list

Tags: python, list, output, whitespace

python convert a long numeric txt file like for example the first 16 million Pi numbers and save it to a list

```
import pandas as pd
file='/home/pp/Pictures/pi.txt'
read_file=pd.read_csv(file)
for row in read_file:
    print(','.join(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

If each line in the file is a digit, then

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    digits = f.readlines()
```

If you need to split the digits (not just one digit per line in the file)

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    digits = list(f.readlines()[0])
```

Comment: I think so a good option will be: with open(file, 'rb') as f: any way thanks a lot I will tray it and later eliminate the white space and garbage